# Show list in groups

Tags: javascript, servlets

From my controller I sent a list to the view

```
Test{
   String first;
   String Last;
}

List<Test> testList = new ArrayList<Test>();
```

`testList` contains following

```
A F
B R
A C
A E
B Q
B P
C I
A L
C E
```

while showing in the view I want it to show as group by way like following

```
(header A)
A F
A C
A E
A L

(header B)
B Q
B P
B R

(header C)
C I
C E
```

This `A,B,C` is not constant. It could be any Value.

How can I show this using JS or jquery

Comment: You would want to do this on the server side, not the client side.

Comment: use jquery .sort() function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $(arr).sort() - method.

HTML:

```
<div id="data"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var ar = new Array();
ar.push({F: "A", L: "C"});
ar.push({F: "B", L: "D"});
ar.push({F: "C", L: "E"});
ar.push({F: "C", L: "X"});
ar.push({F: "A", L: "Z"});

var c = $(ar).sort(function(a,b) {
   var f1 = a.F;
    var f2 = b.F;
    return f1 > f2;
});

$.each(c,function() {
    $("#data").append($("<p>").append(this.F + " " + this.L));
})
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Q7cpm/

**EDIT:** New link to demo with Headers: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7cpm/2/

Comment: I think you are using Array.prototype.sort... Do you know if returning a boolean from your compare function is supported, I googled but did not find the answer ?

Comment: Hi Olivier!
If use `var c = ar.sort(function(a,b) {` instead of `var c = $(ar).sort(function(a,b) {` the result will be same.
Array.prototype.sort has optional parameter for sortfunction - [Link to w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) and you can use it.

Comment: Still I think you should update your answer to return `f1 > f2 ? 1 : -1`

Comment: Hey @P R, thanks for your answer. it worked fine for me. i was wondering if the second column was numbers then could i get the total of individual section, like the header on top? how can I do this??